How do I force a particular window to always be on top?
Under Ubuntu 20.04, I have an application that runs Chromium in kiosk mode (under Docker, if it matters), and I would like it to ALWAYS stay on top.  Sometimes, however, after restarting the browser, the row of desktop icons along the left is displayed above part of the browser window.
It only happens sometimes, but it seems like it's not as unusual an occurrence as it used to be.
I would love to either force a specific window to always be on top of EVERYTHING, or possibly even get rid of the desktop entirely, given that the only thing this should ever be displaying is the browser window.  (At the moment, when our application restarts, the desktop is seen, but I'd love to have a blank screen instead)
Suggestions?  Chromium is already being run with the --kiosk-mode flag.

Your question implies that you are not running Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 but fails to say what you are using. Please edit the question and add this info.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.  Asking about 20.04 would be on-topic; the inclusion of 18.04 makes question off-topic though

If you don't want to see the desktop; why are you using it?  Have you thought about just using a WM; as by default many of those don't even have wallpapers (thus black screen is default), no panels etc will show.. Handle via wmctrl etc

I am not expert on this, but disabling gdm and running something like xinit /bin/chromium during login may do what you want. A good answer by an expert will be appreciated.

@guiverc - everything is funneled through the desktop environment; finding information on how NOT to use it is more difficult than you might think.  A pointer to (actual) documentation on how to manipulate a screen without using a desktop environment would be gratefully received.   Also, fine about 18.04 - it's exactly the same issue, so I removed it from the question

@FedKad that sounds promising - info on how to run xinit instead of some desktop env would be helpful
